# C# checking white space in a textbox

Tags: c#

How can I check in C# that is there a white space only in a textbox and perform some operation after that?

Comment: You just want to know if this has white space in it? Or is a null/blank string acceptable? if you actually want white space you could use regex. pattern = ^\s+$

Comment: How come 10k views? :(

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This ensures multiple spaces are caught in your check.

```
 bool hasAllWhitespace = txtBox1.Text.Length>0 &&
                         txtBox1.Text.Trim().Length==0;
```

To check for a single space only:

```
 bool hasSingleWhitespace = txtBox1.Text == " ";
```

Answer (score 6):

Check the `Text` property of the textbox using [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx).

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTextBox.Text) && myTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Since `IsNullOrWiteSpace` will return true if the textbox is empty (or the property is null), adding the `Length` check ensures that there is something within the text box. The combination of the tests ensures a true if there is only whitespace in the textbox.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, @"\s",)) {
    // do your code
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Some LINQ fun:

```
bool isWhitespace = txtBox.Text.All(char.IsWhiteSpace);
```

Comment: bool isWhitespace = txtBox.Text.All(char.IsWhiteSpace);

Comment: @Bear Monkey: Genius, will change.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtBox.Text))
{
    // so stuff
}
```

Comment: this is only in .net 4 though - there is no part for whitespace in .net 3.5

Comment: And the OP askes to find out if there _is_ only whitespace, not if it is empty/null.

Comment: Is this an extension method?  Using .NET 4, I see String.IsNullOrEmpty and String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace, but not String.IsNullOrEmptyOrWhiteSpace.

Answer (score 1):

```
txtBox.Text.Length == 1 && char.IsWhiteSpace( txtBox.Text.First() );
```

Comment: what if the second char isn't whitespace?

Comment: `txtBox.Text.Length == 1`. There is no second char.

Comment: yes i know that but there could be more than 1 white space char and your solution doesn't work then

Comment: According to the question, there could not - or I'm getting "a white space only" wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (txtBox.Text.equals(" ")))
{
 // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: this will only find a space, not all white space.

Comment: if i enter 10 spaces then what?

Comment: @mazhar kaunain baig, I read "that is there **a white space only** in a textbox" in your question.

Answer (score 0):

```
        var Rxwhitesp = new Regex(@"\s");

        string textboxstring = textbox.Text;
        string textboxfirststring = textbox.Text.First().ToString();
        if (Rxwhitesp.IsMatch(textboxfirststring) && (textboxstring.Length == 1))
        {
            // write code for true condition
        }
        else
        {
            // write code for false condition
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//SIMPLE WAY TO VALIDATE EMPTY SPACES
if (txtusername.Text.Contains(" "))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username");
    txtusername.Clear();
    txtusername.Focus();
}
```