# Check White Space in textbox (C#)

Tags: c#

How to check white space in TextBox?. I want to take username as input, but there shouldn't be any white space. How to check that by returning true false?

Comment: Or of you don't want any space at all (including in the middle), use something like `input.Replace(" ","")`

Comment: That would be great if u show some effort

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
bool isWhitespace = txtBox.Text.Any(char.IsWhiteSpace);
```

This question is already resolved **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803778/c-sharp-checking-white-space-in-a-textbox)**

Comment: Here the question is different from the link. "But there shouldn't be any space.". And the answer should really be `!txtBox.Text.Any(char.IsWhiteSpace)`.

Answer (score 0):

> But there shouldn't be any space.

Use `Trim()` string function

```
textbox1.Text.Trim()
```

> How to check space in text box?

```
bool containspaces = str.Where(c => char.IsWhiteSpace(c)).Count() > 0;
```

Comment: That whill check if the textBox is empty. He said **"there shouldn't be any white space"**

Comment: @Rodolfo, yes misread the post. `Trim()` is what he is looking for. See edit.

Comment: Alright. But, he is explicitly asking a way to **check** if the value is **true** or **false**, not a way to remove the white spaces

Comment: @Rodolfo, OP post is confusing. he actually said both want to check and want to remove. Either way both have been answered now I believe. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: Yeah, it's confusing, maybe he wants to remove it but not asked correctly. Hope we helped anyway