# My combobox although not having a value is having a value. c# winform

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Let's say I have a 5 textbox and 1 combobox and I make the value inputted pass to a variable like this

```
name = textboxName.Text.ToString();
address = txtboxAddress.Text.ToString();
destination = comboboxDestination.Text.ToString(); // combobox
position = txtboxPosition.Text.ToString();
station = txtboxStation.Text.ToString();
purpose = richtxtboxPurpose.Text.ToString();
```

Then I wanted to check if their value is null or just blank space.

```
int switchCase = 0;

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && name.Length > 0 ||
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address) && address.Length > 0 ||
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(destination) && destination.Length > 0 ||
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(position) && position.Length > 0 ||
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(station) && station.Length > 0 ||
    string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(purpose) && purpose.Length > 0
    )
{
    switchCase = 2;
}
else 
{
    switchCase = 1;
}
```

then for my trap is this

```
switch (switchCase)
{ 
    case 1:
        MessageBox.Show("Profile created!");                     
    break;

    case 2:
        MessageBox.Show("Please complete the form to procede.");
    break;
}
```

The problem is if I just load up the page and didnt typed anything it is going to the `case 1` which means that all of my textboxes and combobox have a value. Then if I key in just `space` in all of the textboxes it reads the condition and go to `case 2` what is going on? 
EDIT:
My first code is like this and it is working well

```
 if (name == "" || address == "" || destination == "" || position == "" || station == "" || purpose == "")
```

Although it is prone to the blank space.

Comment: Did you try to change the combobox to dropdownlist

Comment: Ah yes, my combobox is in dropdownlist.

Comment: @Rob I understand , but why is this guy have 5 upvotes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803778/c-sharp-checking-white-space-in-a-textbox the second answer to the top. i can't understand why must he add the length check so I just use it maybe because it's robust coding

Comment: Oh im sorry. Btw, I used your `!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)` but I remove the `!` and it works. care to explain it with the answer please? `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here:

`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name) && name.Length > 0` is checking if the string is empty, entirely whitespace, or null. Then you add a length check, effectively changing it into 'only accept strings which contain whitespace, but not blank.

Removing the length check should work as expected.

In addition, you can clean up the code a bit, to reduce repetitiveness:

```
if (new[] { name, address, destination, position, station, purpose }
    .Any(str => string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))) 
{
    ....
}
```